# Camel doesn't catch Exception

Tags: java, exception, apache-camel, dsl, spring-camel

```
.from("seda:rest_upload")
                .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) {
                        if(true){
                            throw new RuntimeException();
                        }})
                .to("seda:parsed_csv")
                .onException(Exception.class).process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                logger.warn("Error");
            }
        });
```

But `logger.warn("Error");`  was not invoked.

What do I wrong?

How can I register global exception handler for camel route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move onException block on top of the route and do not forget on `end()` terminator.

`end()` tells Camel, where the onException block ends. If you ommit that, Camel treats it as one `onException` block. Simply there will be route consuming from seda and no output processor, because everything after `onException()` gets part of `onException` block.

---

**Route-specific exception handling:** 
Handle exceptions occured in route `seda:rest_upload`

```
from("seda:rest_upload")
    .onException(Exception.class).process(exchange -> logger.warn("Error")).end()
    .process(e -> {throw new RuntimeException();})
    .to("seda:parsed_csv");

from("seda:parsed_csv").to("log:parsed_csv");

from("timer:tmr?period=1000")
    .setBody(constant("mock"))
    .to("seda:rest_upload");
```

---

**Global exception handling**: Handle exceptions in all routes in current `RouteBuilder`

```
onException(Exception.class).process(exchange -> logger.warn("Error")); //There is no need for end(), whole block is part of onException block

from("seda:rest_upload")
    .process(e -> {throw new RuntimeException();})
    .to("seda:parsed_csv");

from("seda:parsed_csv").to("log:parsed_csv");

from("timer:tmr?period=1000")
    .setBody(constant("mock"))
    .to("seda:rest_upload");
```

Comment: Will it catch exception which will be thrown before seda:rest_upload? I want to have global handler. What if I will not use *end()*?